# Creating own ribbon with MapCad tools in Mapinfo Pro

Tags: mapinfo

I just updated Mapinfo Pro from 15 (32bit) to 16 (64bit). At work, I use the Mapcad tools. I tried to create my own ribbon with only Mapcad tools, but I don't have them in the Customize Ribbon dialog box. Or I cann't find them.

Does anyone know where to find them?

For example, I cann't find tool "update column with text object".

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can only create a custom ribbon tab with standard MapInfo Pro controls.

We are looking into a way to also let you select controls from other running custom applications such as MapCAD.